# LibGDX - How to export a texture as a .png onto, say, the desktop

Tags: java, libgdx, textures, export, png

I'm making a game in which I need to export a texture which the user has edited as a .png into a specified location. I'd like it if I could have the default saving window thing (like on other apps when you do cmd+s). If this isn't possible, is there any way in GDX to export a texture (as a .png) to the computer (and preferably not the assets folder)

Answer (score 1):

One way of achieving this would be to save the portion of the screen where they've made their edits by taking a screen shot using the `ScreenUtils.getFrameBufferPixmap` method and then dumping the `Pixmap` data to a file using the `PixmapIO` class that can write **PNG**s from a `Pixmap`.

```
public class ScreenshotFactory {

private static int counter = 1;
public static void saveScreenshot(){
    try{
        FileHandle fh;
        do{
            fh = new FileHandle("screenshot" + counter++ + ".png");
        }while (fh.exists());
        Pixmap pixmap = getScreenshot(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), false);
        PixmapIO.writePNG(fh, pixmap);
        pixmap.dispose();
    }catch (Exception e){           
    }
}

private static Pixmap getScreenshot(int x, int y, int w, int h, boolean yDown){
    final Pixmap pixmap = ScreenUtils.getFrameBufferPixmap(x, y, w, h);

    if (yDown) {
        // Flip the pixmap upside down
        ByteBuffer pixels = pixmap.getPixels();
        int numBytes = w * h * 4;
        byte[] lines = new byte[numBytes];
        int numBytesPerLine = w * 4;
        for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
            pixels.position((h - i - 1) * numBytesPerLine);
            pixels.get(lines, i * numBytesPerLine, numBytesPerLine);
        }
        pixels.clear();
        pixels.put(lines);
        pixels.clear();
    }

    return pixmap;
}
}
```

The snippet above is snagged from [Take a Screenshot](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Take-a-Screenshot) for **libGDX** on github. It should be easy to modify it to take only a portion of the screen or to change it to work on a `Pixmap` grabbed from another `FrameBuffer`.

Comment: But how would I export this to _anywhere_ on the computer, not just assets, for example onto the desktop.

Comment: Use the following path with the FileHandle: System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Desktop/picname.png" , but keep in mind that this is not guaranteed to work in every case. There are already separate questions debating this topic on stackexchange, just search a bit!

Comment: The constructor I've used on the `FileHandle` class is the one that sets the type of file to `Absolute`, this means you can specify a full path to a folder anywhere on your machine. It won't be portable beyond the Desktop version, but I guess that's not something you care about in this case.